# Is the Classical definition of probability circular?

Tags: probability

The Classical definition of probability is defined as "the ratio of the number of favorable cases to the number of all cases possible when nothing leads us to expect that any one of these cases should occur more than any other, which renders them, for us, equally possible." To me, this definition still sounds circular. What does it precisely mean for a series of events to be "equally possible" and what does it mean for an event to "occur more than any other"? Is it talking about one event occuring more frequently than other events as you repeat the experiment?

Comment: May I know the source of your quote regarding the definition of probability?

Comment: That definition is definitely inadequate due to not explaining what "equally possible" means. The axiomatic approach to probability avoids or sidesteps the difficulty of defining probability precisely.

Comment: The quote is from wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_definition_of_probability. I have seen similar definitions from other sources as well.

Comment: It's weird to say it's from wikipedia.  Better to say it's attributed to Laplace's Théorie analytique des probabilités,

Comment: From what I have read, this inadequcy of not defining what "equally possible" means is the reason that the Principle of indifference was proposed (please correct me if I am wrong). But even with this principle in place, I feel like the definition is still circular.

Comment: Basically,  math was informal and had poor foundations.   Then we fixed that.  For probability, we did it by building it on top of measure theory.